# Haskell, return a tuple

Tags: haskell

i have this code, it's the formulae of combination without repetitions:

```
combinaciones   ::  Int ->[Int]->[[Int]]
combinaciones   0   _   =   [[]]
combinaciones   _   []  =   []
combinaciones   k   (x:xs)  =   [x:ys | ys <- combinaciones (k - 1) xs] ++ combinaciones k xs

combinationsN   ::  Int ->Int->[[Int]]
combinationsN   n   k   =   combinaciones   k   [1..n]
```

My problem is that i want return a list of lists with the number of lists in the list, a couple: ([[Int]], Int). How can i do that?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "tuple".

Comment: Yes! Haha, Do you know how can i solve this problem? :-(

Comment: This is tutorial-level material: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/YAHT/Language_basics#Pairs.2C_Triples_and_More

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple version - it's probably possible to do it more efficiently by counting along, but this is what I can come up with at 1am.

```
combinationsWithCount :: Int -> [Int] -> ([[Int]], Int)
combinationsWithCount n xs = let cs = combinaciones n xs
                             in (cs, length cs)
```

Edit: OK, let me try to write the smart version too.

```
combinaciones   ::  Int -> [Int] -> ([[Int]], Int)
combinaciones   0   _   =   ([[]], 1)
combinaciones   _   []  =   ([], 0)
combinaciones   k   (x:xs)  =
    let (first, firstN) = combinaciones (k - 1) xs
        (second, secondN) = combinaciones k xs
    in ([x:ys | ys <- first] ++ second, firstN + secondN)
```

Absolutely no guarantees that this does the right thing, I'm half-asleep. ;-)

Comment: Hahahaha thanks! It show me this: Syntax error in expression (unexpected `(') and i don't see where miss a parenthesis!